# Baked normals are rendered too dark

Tags: rendering, normals, normal-map

Solved: answered below by @Alexis King

I am a bit of a newbie to all of this and I ran into a problem when trying to bake the normal that I've made to a normal map. The problem is that the object gets darker and I have no idea why. Can anyone help me?

Here are the non-baked normals:

[image: Render]

[image: Material settings]

And here are the baked normals:

[image: Render]

[image: Material settings]

[image: Bake settings]

Both rendered in Cycles with the same lights in the scene and the same settings. It's a single object with a single material, all faces have been recalculated and look fine.

If it's of any help, in Eevee the non-baked normal map looks like this:

[image: Non baked Render]

And the baked normal map like this:

[image: Baked Render]

Comment: You need to use a *Normal Map* node between your normal map texture and the shader’s Normal socket.

Comment: @AlexisKing I see it worked quite nicely, thank you!